# mockObject.setProperty not working in PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a code:

```
A a = someOtherObject.someMethod();
if(null != a)
{
   if(a.getPropertyOfA().equals("testValue"))
   {
       //some code
```

This is a part of a method.

Now using powerMockito, when I try to create a testCase,
I wrote the following code snippet:

```
A a = PowerMockito.mock(A.class);
a.setPropertyOfA("testValue");
//some other code
```

But on running the code,
during JUnit run, the value of the property is shown to be null. Why is the Property value not set to the value set by me, in the test  class?

Do I have to instantiate the object, instead of mocking it?

Is the someMethod() method call of the method causing any error?

Comment: Why don't you set a return value for `getPropertyOfA`?

Comment: I even tried that. But it was for a mock object of A. Should I try with instantiation for that?

Comment: Is it the same `A` instance as returned by `someMethod()`?

Comment: You are calling the setter on a mock, meaning it won't have any effect. I recommend you read the documentation.

Comment: @Sotirios yes, it is for the same `A`

Comment: @Ray `setPropertyOfA` wont work? so can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is like this then you first mock A. Then give it a behavior.

```
A mockA = mock(A.class);
when(mockA.getPropertyOfa()).thenReturn("testValue");
```

So when your A instance is called for property of A, it'll return "testValue".

Comment: Thank you. But still getting getPropertyOfA as null.

Comment: Can you post your exact code instead of A and Bs. We are probably missing something